# CORS OPTIONS preflight requests not showing in dev tools

Tags: safari, cors, preflight, safari-web-inspector

How to get Safari to display CORS pre-flight OPTIONS requests in the dev tools network tab?

IIRC they used to show up, and I know the requests are being made as we can see them logging on the server.

We had the same problem suddenly occur with Chrome in the last few weeks (around Chrome 79/80) and had to force it by setting `chrome://flags/#out-of-blink-cors` to `disable`

Comment: I raised https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213215. Please consider cc’ing yourself on that

Comment: @stringy05, this sounds like a regression. What version of Safari are you using? Does this also happen in Safari Technology Preview? Please comment on the bug link above or send me a message on SO or Twitter.

Comment: Safari 13.1.1 and Safari TP 13.2 for me.

Comment: Still an issue in Safari 14.0

Comment: And still an issue in Safari 15.1

Comment: And still an issue in Safari 15.5

Comment: Earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224023/why-dont-i-see-preflight-method-options-xhr-requests-in-safari-developer-too

Comment: And... still an issue in Safari 15.6

Comment: And.. still an issue in Safari 17.0.

Comment: I think this will be an issue forever. It seems like the cors out of blink thing is a security change to move the CORS request into some sort of sandbox and that means it's lost to the network monitor? I dont know why this can't be monitored easily (given web page requests happen inside the sandbox??) but been an issue for a long time now. Very frustrating