Unable to upload directly to S3 from iOS Safari on a cellular network due to CORS issues
I'm stumped with this one issue on iOS Safari where I'm unable to upload files directly to S3 due to a CORS issue. Meanwhile on iOS it works for Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Moreover it works on Safari when connected to WiFi, but fails on a cellular network.
Here's my AWS S3 Bucket CORS configuration
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "Accept",
            "Cache-Control",
            "Content-Type",
            "Origin",
            "origin",
            "Pragma",
            "Referer",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site",
            "User-Agent",
            "X-Requested-With",
            "x-requested-with"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://app.com",
            "https://app.com/",
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 300
    }
]

and here's the error:
[Error] Origin https://app.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 400
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://aws.s3.link due to access control checks.

the file upload code is using axios
// Multi-part upload: Uploads file parts to S3 using presigned URLs
uploadFileParts = async (
    asset: File | Blob,
    presignedUrls: { url: string; partNumber: number }[],
) => {
    const parts = [];

    let curr = 0,
      partLength = 0;
    let remaining = asset.size;
    for (let i = 0; i < presignedUrls.length; i++) {
      const { url, partNumber } = presignedUrls[i];

      if (remaining < MAX_PART_SIZE) {
        partLength = remaining;
      } else {
        partLength = MAX_PART_SIZE;
      }

      const chunk = asset.slice(curr, curr + partLength);
      const response = await axios.put(url, chunk, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          Pragma: 'no-cache',
        },
      });

      remaining -= partLength;
      curr += partLength;
      if (response.status === 200) {
        parts.push({
          ETag: response.headers.etag,
          PartNumber: partNumber,
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to upload part');
      }
    }

    return parts;
};

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

what's lame about Safari Devtools is that the preflight requests are not visible, following these steps do nothing. Makes it hard to debug the instance when it successfully uploads a file via WiFi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290892/cors-options-preflight-requests-not-showing-in-dev-tools

We've got exactly the same problem, can't work it out, is happening for us in Chrome, Safari, and other mobile browsers as well. Not just isolated to iOS but also have been able to reproduce in Android. Works on WiFi sometimes but never on 4G / 5G.

Fix:
Settings > Apps > Safari > Advanced > Feature Flags > Toggle 'Enable experimental network loader' on and off
Seems to be a bug with the current version of IOS and safari.
Check out this post on the apple developer forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/764420
